# ffmpeg rtmp broadcast on youtube speed below 1x

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp

i made an python and opencv program that produce frame per second around 8-15fps with MJPEG output format where MJPEG address served on localhost webserver (0.0.0.0:5000) and, i do attempt to broadcast its frame to rtmp server like youtube using ffmpeg so basically i do convert MJEG to flv and forward to rtmp server with following command `ffmpeg -f  mjpeg -i http://0.0.0.0:5000/video_feed -f lavfi -i anullsrc -c:v libx264 -vf "scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:320,unsharp=lx=3:ly=3:la=1.0" -crf 24 -c:a aac -ac 1 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxx-xxx-xxx` but unfortunatelly youtube stream has too many buffering that occur every around 5 second and ffmpeg terminal tell that writing speed is only around 0.317x (expected to be sync with youtube around 0.99-1x), my question is

does there a way to stream 'realtime' around 8-15fps and automatically sync with youtube rtmp server without buffering because i thought that youtube require around 30fps while my fps only 9-15fps that probably causing buffer.
do there an such like additional ffmpeg's parameter that able to speed up writing? thank you

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A raw video will usually be assigned a framerate of 25. But your source is variable frame rate. You need to assign wallclock time as timestamp and generate a constant frame rate output for YT.

`ffmpeg -f mjpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps true -i http://0.0.0.0:5000/video_feed -f lavfi -re -i anullsrc -vsync cfr -r 25 -c:v libx264 -vf "scale=trunc(oh*a/2)*2:320,unsharp=lx=3:ly=3:la=1.0" -crf 24 -c:a aac -ac 1 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxx-xxx-xxx`